# Matlab sprintf incorrect result using random strings from list

Tags: string, matlab, list, printf

I want create a string variable using ´sprintf´ and a random name from a list (in order to save an image with such a name). A draft of the code is the following:

```
Names = [{'C'} {'CL'} {'SCL'} {'A'}];
nameroulette = ceil(rand(1)*4)
filename = sprintf('DG_%d.png', Names{1,nameroulette});
```

But when I check `filename`, what I get is the text I typed followed not by one of the strings, but by a number that I have no idea where it comes from. For example, if my `nameroulette = 1` then `filename` is `DG_67.png`, and if `nameroulette = 4`, `filename = 'DG_65.png'` . Where does this number come from and how can I fix this problem?

Comment: With `sprintf` the `%d` identifier is for an integer, i.e. it inserts an integer where the `%d` appears. I imagine that what you are getting are the [ASCII values](http://www.asciitable.com/) of the characters of the string (`'A'` is `65` so `'C'` would be `67`) To insert the string as characters instead of numbers, rather use `%s`. Check out [this section  of the `sprintf` docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html#inputarg_formatSpec)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to change

```
filename = sprintf('DG_%d.png', Names{1,nameroulette});
```

to

```
filename = sprintf('DG_%s.png', Names{1,nameroulette});
```

By the way you may want to have a look at randi command for drawing random integers.

Comment: Ah ok, it was easier than I thought. Thank you a lot and also for the suggestion of ´randsample´to replace my ´nameroulette´ variable.